# How to send emails with attachments located on disc using PL/SQL?

Tags: email, plsql, smtp, email-attachments

I have a ready script which sends email using PL/SQL. It has been stored in a procedure and when it is called by passing proper parameters, it sends email.

Now, I need to pick up a file from the disc and send it as an attachment. I have seen many examples where the data is stored in BLOB and comes from the DB. In my case it is not from DB instead it is a file on the server/disc.

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

ORACLE DIRECTORIES can be used to achieve this.

[link to a full email/smtp example](http://www.oracletool.com/blog/?p=64)

Comment: you should mention that link is to a full email/smtp example.. and not just the doco for oracle directories.

Answer (score 0):

Use [UTL_FILE](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_file.htm#ARPLS069) to read data from disk.

You can find a good example of how to use it to load an entire file into a BLOB in the [Alexandria PL/SQL Library](https://github.com/mortenbra/alexandria-plsql-utils). Look at (or just copy!) the code from `file_util_pkg.get_blob_from_file`.